# Show the Memory Window in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I've been trying for half an hour to find and toggle/show the memory window in VS2008, but no success. Can someone show where it is buried in the menus?

In VC6 I would toggle it from View->Debug Windows->Memory.

[image]

Comment: There are four of them.  Show the first one with Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1.  Click around a bit while you're at it, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in debug mode got to Debug->Windows->Memory or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>. so it says in my `VS2008`. :)